# Pointer program not working but syntax should be right? Why is it not compiling?

Tags: c++

This is the original program and I can't seem to find the program that is causing it to fail to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "How many integers you wish to enter? ";
    int InputNums = 0;
    cin >> InputNums;

    int* pNumbers = new int [InputNums]; // Allocate request integers.
    int* pCopy = pNumbers;

    cout << "Successfully allocated memory for: " << InputNums << " integers." << endl;
    for (int Index = 0; Index < InputNums ; ++ Index){
        cout << "Enter number: " << Index << ": ";
        cin >> *(pNumbers + Index);
    }

    cout << "Displaying all numbers input: " << endl;
    for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
        cout << *(pCopy++) << " ";

        cout << endl;

        // Done w/using pointers? Release memory.
        delete[] pNumbers;

        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas of why this isn't working? I've looked and tried to insert some ';' to no avail. so I redid them in original form but any ideas would be appreciated!

These are the error(s):

```
main.cpp:20:24: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
main.cpp:20:24: error: expected ';' before 'int'
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is standard C++; I'll edit the tag list appropriately. The only thing I can see (and it's something I've never tried) is the dual declaration in the final for loop, _viz._ `int Index = 0, int* pCopy...`. Any reason you can't reuse the pCopy you already have?

Comment: Well I'm following a guide really, it should work. Is there a reasoning or explanation of why it wouldn't work or why I can't use the dual declaration?

Comment: You should be following a C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you where the error is:

```
for(int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
```

does not make sense. The problem is in the first part of the `for` loop:

```
int Index = 0, int* pCopy = pNumbers;
```

The compiler expects that after declaring a variable, the statement ends and the second declaration is in a new statement (although another option exists which we will see later):

```
int Index = 0; int* pCopy = pNumbers;
```

This however breaks the `for`, as it expects one (simple) statement and two expressions. [It can be fixed](https://ideone.com/xKPFZ1) by writing

```
int Index = 0, *pCopy = pNumbers;
```

which is a variation on something you may have seen before:

```
int a, b;
```

with some more complications added in - mainly initialization and the fact that the `*` does not really belong to the type, but to the variable (which is weird and a great source of errors).

Of course all that is not really necessary, as you already have a `pCopy` that holds the exactly right value anyway...

Comment: It's not got much to do with the `for`, even; it's just a basic rule of single-statement multiple-declarations.

Comment: Which cannot be split into two statements due to the `for` context :)

Comment: Because it's a statement. And because it starts with a typename.

Comment: This works and the solution works. I understand it even better now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare two different types of variables in one declaration statement. Think of it as trying to do the same in normal declaration:

```
    int a = 1, double b = 1.0;
```

Clearly against C++ syntax. Same thing in for loop declaration.

You could try this:

```
    for(int Index = 0, *pCopy = pNumbers; Index < InputNums; ++Index)
```

That compiles, but personally I find it a bit iffy. I think it's much better style to simply move the pCopy declaration outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The second operand to a comma expression must be an expression. A declaration is not an expression (an assignment would be, but initialisation is not assignment).

Comment: There is no "comma expression" here.

Comment: For (int index=0, (comma...) is a comma expression